# groupby/sum all columns in first column identical awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that has n columns in it (dont know how many columns in advance). I need to sum columns having identical column1 values and print them. All columns are numeric except first column. For example

file1.txt

```
col1 col2 col3 ... colN
val1 3000 1000 ... 5000 
val2 3000 1000 ... 5000
val1 1000 2000 ... 3000
```

expected output:

```
col1 col2 col3 ... colN
val1 4000 3000 ... 8000 
val2 3000 1000 ... 5000
```

I have tried:

```
awk '{sums[$1] += $2} END { for (i in sums) printf("%s %s\n", i, sums[i])}' file1.txt | sort
```

This prints only first two columns. I need to add and print all columns.

Comment: That seems to me to be exactly the right idea but you are going to need to loop over every field and do that sums work for each one. You can use `sums[$1,i]` (assuming your loop variable is i) to have an array index based on both the value of `$1` and the field number. Then your END loop is just going to have to walk from 1 to X (save NF at some point and use that assuming all your lines are the same length) and print out sequential fields.

Answer (score 6):

this should work:

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next}
    {b[$1];for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[$1,i]+=$i}
    END{for(x in b){
            printf "%s ",x;
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
                printf "%s" (i==NF?"\n":" "),a[x,i]}}' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
col1 col2 col3 colN
val1 3000 1000 5000 
val2 3000 1000 5000
val1 1000 2000 3000

kent$  awk 'NR==1{print;next}
        {b[$1];for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[$1,i]+=$i}
        END{for(x in b){printf "%s ",x;
                        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
                           printf "%s" (i==NF?"\n":" "),a[x,i]}}' f
col1 col2 col3 colN
val1 4000 3000 8000
val2 3000 1000 5000
```

Comment: Thanks Kent, It worked with a little unexpected formatting in result file. a column that has a value "42713877753" gets formatted to "4.27139e+10". I want to preserve the column value the way they are, if they are untouched. Any idea?

Comment: Hi Kent, Thanks!! I got the formatting correct by placing %d instead of %s. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: `printf "%s" (i==NF?"\n":" "),a[x,i]` is very odd syntax. Why not `printf "%s%s", a[x,i], (i==NF?"\n":" ")`? IMHO that's clearer since the separator char comes after the data in the script just like it does in the output and you're explicitly/clearly using the printf formatting string. I'd actually use `printf "%s%s", a[x,i], (i<NF?OFS:ORS)` rather than hard-coding the values and IMHO it makes more sense written with the OFS before the ORS than the other way around but nbd. +1 anyway.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks. yes you are right. When I read the codes again, I feel strange too. I think why I got that is, first test without those format stuff, and chk the output, oh, there I need something, just put the strange stuff there.... :(  the `%s%s` variant is wise way.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk by `arrays of arrays`, if your GNU awk is above version 4.1

```
awk 'NR==1{print;next}
{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1][i]+=$i}
END { for (i in a) 
        {  printf i
          for (j=2;j<=length(a[i])+1;j++) 
              printf FS a[i][j]
          printf RS
        }
    }' file
```