# Sum of specific columns data with based on date using awk

Tags: awk

I am having a data which is separated by a comma

```
LBA0SF004,2018-10-01,4681,4681 
LBA0SF004,2018-10-01,919,919 
LBA0SF004,2018-10-01,3,3 
LBA0SF004,2018-10-01,11453,11453

LBA0SF004,2018-10-02,4681,4681 
LBA0SF004,2018-10-02,1052,1052 
LBA0SF004,2018-10-02,3,3 
LBA0SF004,2018-10-02,8032,8032
```

I need an awk command to add all 3rd and 4th columns with awk command based on date. If you see the same server with different dates values are available I need data like this

```
LBA0SF004 2018-10-01 17056 17056 
LBA0SF004 2018-10-02 13768 13768
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Prior to kvantour's edit, [it looked a **lot**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52611090/1) like you'd copied-and-pasted something from elsewhere on SO (perhaps a previous question of your own that you've now deleted)? I suggest not doing that.

Comment: thanks for editing it correct way

Comment: There is some information missing. What happens if column 1 changes?

Comment: Try the following `awk -F, '{a[$1 OFS $2]+=$3;b[$1 OFS $2]+=$4}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i],b[i]}' inputfile`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [groupby/sum all columns in first column identical awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140065/groupby-sum-all-columns-in-first-column-identical-awk)

Answer (score 0):

Below GNU AWK construct should be able to do what you are looking for.

```
awk '
BEGIN {
   FS = ","
   OFS = " "
}
{
   if(NF == 4)
   {
      a[$1][$2]["3rd"] += $3;
      a[$1][$2]["4th"] += $4;
   }
}
END {
    for (i in a)
    {
       for (j in a[i])
       {
          print i, j, a[i][j]["3rd"], a[i][j]["4th"];
       }
    }
}
' Input_File.txt
```

Explanation :-

FS is input field Separator which in your case is `,`

OFS is output field Separator which is

Create an array `a` with first column, second column and sum of third and forth columns

At the END, Print the contents of the array

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays. Also `a[$1][$2]["3rd"] =  a[$1][$2]["3rd"] + $3;` = `a[$1][$2]["3rd"] += $3`.

Comment: As mentioned, it will work only with GNU awk (GAWK).

Comment: Normally awk command will work in our environment but this is showing syntax error, is there any alternate command

Comment: You can try the solution mentioned in question's comment. BTW what is syntax error you are getting ? Also can you please run this `awk -W version` and check which AWK you are using.

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7 , this is the awk version we are using

Comment: > BEGIN {
>    FS = ","
>    OFS = " "
> }
> {
>    if(NF == 4)
>    {
>       a[$1][$2]["3rd"] += $3;
>       a[$1][$2]["4th"] += $4;
>    }
> }
> END {
>     for (i in a)
>     {
>        for (j in a[i])
>        {
>           print i, j, a[i][j]["3rd"], a[i][j]["4th"];
>        }
>     }
> }
> ' value.txt

Comment: awk: cmd. line:9:       a[$1][$2]["3rd"] += $3;
awk: cmd. line:9:            ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:10:       a[$1][$2]["4th"] += $4;
awk: cmd. line:10:            ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:16:        for (j in a[i])
awk: cmd. line:16:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:18:           print i, j, a[i][j]["3rd"], a[i][j]["4th"];
awk: cmd. line:18:                           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:18:           print i, j, a[i][j]["3rd"], a[i][j]["4th"];
awk: cmd. line:18:                                           ^ syntax error

Comment: In GNU AWK 3.1.7, above multidimensional array syntax is NOT supported. I believe it is supported in 4.0 above. So, you can try the one given in kvantour's comment. Here we emulate multidimensional array by concatenating two indices. For 3.1.7, you refer this documentation. [3.1.7 Multidimensional Array](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/unix/unixguide/infohtml/gawk/gawk.html#Multi_002ddimensional). [4.0 above Multidimensional Array](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html)